# Can not secure AngularJS page using Spring Security

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, google-app-engine, spring-security

I am using spring security to secure my app with the below configuration to try and display Spring default login page:

**spring-security.xml**

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="test.account" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My problem is that all resources are succesfully authenticated excpet the Angular file (localhost:8080/#/notification) which is always open to public.

**Edit 1**:

I've tried to run the above spring security configuration on Jetty server and it works great. The problem only appears when using Google AppEngine even after adding `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` to appengine-web.xml.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is because that request never travels to the server. The hashbang is resolved entirely in the client. What you may need to protect is the view associated with that hashbang, so that when you try to get that partial view it is protected by your security policy.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Thank you for your help, what  is the best practice to secure my /index.html page?

Comment: Spring counts on the fact that the MVC is in the server side. But Angukar transfers all the MVC to the client side.

Comment: @QhadR then there is no way to secure it using Spring security?

Comment: Please check question updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to secure static files using Spring MVC on Google AppEngine using the `<security-constraint>` attribute of the web.xml file.

Example:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/xyz</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/yyz/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Here, can we secure static pages by role of a user?